# Perform validation on a record when clicking on a custom button

Tags: visualforce, redirect

I would like to have some sort of validation when a custom button on a lead record is clicked.
So if the lead record is not satisfying some conditions, an error message will be displayed to the user.
Otherwise, a visualforce page will be opened to perform some logic.

Currently the validation is executed in the visualforce page. however, I am not able to redirect the user to the standard lead record page **and show some error message.**

Is there any best practice for this ?
Hope that JS along with window.alert is not the only way to achieve this. :)

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Please **[edit] your post** to share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript on your button. Use the "Execute JavaScript" option.

```
if({!somefield <> "some value"}) {
    alert("This record is not in the correct state to do this.");
} else {
    window.top.location.href = "{!JSENCODE(URLFOR($Page.pageName, null, [id=record.Id]))}";
}
```

Comment: thanks sfdcfox,
Is there anyway to manipulate with jQuery the standard page to display some nice looking error message?

Comment: @RonDaniel sure, you can use RequireScript to import jQuery and a nice lightbox library and display whatever you want. It simply won't work in lightning, though.